# How to get specific JSON values for a given key of a JMeter response?

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I want to extract some data and store it as JMeter variables of a previous sampler response. In my response, there are many, so called, attributes which have a formulaName, a definitionId and a id. I want to find a specific attribute via the formulaName ("formulaName": "F1"; defined is user defined variables) and get it's definitionId and id and store them in a variable like attributeF1DefinitionId and attributeF1Id. 
On the bottom of the question a complete JSON response can be found, which was not shortened to better describe my problem.

```
{
    "resultType": "OK",
    "messages": null,
    "results": {
         "data": {
             "actionData": {
                "actionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "modelId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "isNew": false,
                "isReadOnly": false,
                "includeDisplayObjectsInTabVisibility": true,
                "preselectedTabId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "elementId": "AM100000001",
                "localizedName": "AM100000001Action",
                "headerLayout": {
                  "fitToAvailableWidth": true,
                  "fillingColumnIndex0Based": 0,
                  "fitToAvailableHeight": false,
                  "fillingRowIndex0Based": null,
                  "attributes": null
                "tabs": [
                  {
                    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "formulaName": "TD1",
                    "name": "Description",
                    "nameAdditionalInfos": null,
                    "dynamicLayout": {
                      "fitToAvailableWidth": false,
                      "fillingColumnIndex0Based": null,
                      "fitToAvailableHeight": false,
                      "fillingRowIndex0Based": null,
                      "attributes": [
                        {
                          "id": "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
                          "name": "Attribute Number 1",
                          "formulaName": "F1",
                          "definitionId": "10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
                          "isHidden": false
                        },
                        {
                          "id": "20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
                          "name": "Attribute Number 2",
                          "formulaName": "F2",
                          "definitionId": "20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
                          "isHidden": false
                        },
                        ......
```

Any approaches are appreciated, where I can automate this extraction in the next step. What I actually want to do, is to extract almost all definitionIds and ids of all attributes (found by their formulaName) and generate use defined variables for them. The formula names are held in a "User defined variables" - Set and I found a way to iterate through it with groovy.

My approach was with a JSR223 - groovy post processor inside the request sampler which loads the data and has the response seen above. 
But im stuck, with the filtering for my specific formulaName.

```
import groovy.json.*;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables;

def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();    
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

def allAttributes = json.results.data.actionData.tabs.dynamicLayout.attributes;
```

Complete JSON response:

```
{
  "resultType": "OK",
  "messages": null,
  "results": {
    "data": {
      "actionData": {
        "actionId": "627292b8-5854-4413-bd3c-7bc4a683f58d",
        "modelId": "da5433d1-74f9-43e4-8a98-92c8eb9dcead",
        "isReadOnly": false,
        "preselectedTabId": "14ff3d76-532d-47a6-bb85-5e48b0e7cab9",
        "elementId": "AM200000001",
        "localizedName": "AM200000001Action",
        "tabs": [
          {
            "id": "14ff3d76-532d-47a6-bb85-5e48b0e7cab9",
            "formulaName": "TD2",
            "name": "Description",
            "clientId": "627292b8-5854-4413-bd3c-7bc4a683f58d_14ff3d76-532d-47a6-bb85-5e48b0e7cab9",
            "nameAdditionalInfos": null,
            "dynamicLayout": {
              "fitToAvailableWidth": false,
              "fillingColumnIndex0Based": null,
              "fitToAvailableHeight": false,
              "fillingRowIndex0Based": null,
              "attributes": [
                {
                  "id": "ca25c1bc-5528-4730-8cc5-3a3c2ca4428b",
                  "name": "F1 attribute name",
                  "formulaName": "F1",
                  "definitionId": "1dc065a6-f071-4547-835b-603aff165754",
                  "isHidden": false,
                  "isReadOnly": false,
                  "isMandatory": true,
                  "label": {
                    "settings": {
                      "bold": false,
                      "underline": false,
                      "color": "#000000",
                      "fontSize": null,
                      "allowTextWrap": true
                    },
                    "text": "F1 attribute name",
                    "colonPosition": 6,
                    "referedClientId": "ca25c1bc-5528-4730-8cc5-3a3c2ca4428b_Value",
                    "clientId": "ca25c1bc-5528-4730-8cc5-3a3c2ca4428b_Label",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 3,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeLabelDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "mandatorySign": {
                    "clientId": "ca25c1bc-5528-4730-8cc5-3a3c2ca4428b_MandatorySign",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 2,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeMandatorySignDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "documentation": {
                    "documentations": [
                      {
                        "id": "a2a4fb71-9662-44e3-9279-b4692f9ca8f1",
                        "name": "Attribute documentation",
                        "type": 2
                      }
                    ],
                    "clientId": "ca25c1bc-5528-4730-8cc5-3a3c2ca4428b_Documentation",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 2,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeDocumentationSignDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "width": 570,
                    "options": [
                      {
                        "id": "402e48f4-a313-4869-9355-91b120a93849",
                        "text": "Planned",
                        "cascadingParentItemIds": []
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "f68bc4d8-ef25-4f02-acf4-bc20cbe45ab0",
                        "text": "Implemented",
                        "cascadingParentItemIds": []
                      }
                    ],
                    "cascadingParentAttributeId": null,
                    "allowsNoValue": true,
                    "cascadingParentInitialValue": null,
                    "value": "402e48f4-a313-4869-9355-91b120a93849",
                    "attributeType": "ActionAttributeListSingleEntity",
                    "isDirty": false,
                    "clientId": "ca25c1bc-5528-4730-8cc5-3a3c2ca4428b_Value",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 1,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeSingleSelectListDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "dependencies": []
                },
                {
                  "id": "c75171ee-bd2f-4396-828e-0f909ae538ed",
                  "name": "F2 attribute name",
                  "formulaName": "F2",
                  "definitionId": "886e8d59-deb5-4725-8080-9033feacb6d3",
                  "isHidden": false,
                  "isReadOnly": false,
                  "isMandatory": true,
                  "label": {
                    "settings": {
                      "bold": false,
                      "underline": false,
                      "color": "#000000",
                      "fontSize": null,
                      "allowTextWrap": true
                    },
                    "text": "F2 attribute name",
                    "colonPosition": 6,
                    "referedClientId": "c75171ee-bd2f-4396-828e-0f909ae538ed_Value",
                    "clientId": "c75171ee-bd2f-4396-828e-0f909ae538ed_Label",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 3,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeLabelDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "mandatorySign": {
                    "clientId": "c75171ee-bd2f-4396-828e-0f909ae538ed_MandatorySign",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 2,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeMandatorySignDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "documentation": {
                    "documentations": [
                      {
                        "id": "734d1c1e-0b35-46f3-9580-7f0a31a8201b",
                        "name": "Attribute documentation",
                        "type": 2
                      }
                    ],
                    "clientId": "c75171ee-bd2f-4396-828e-0f909ae538ed_Documentation",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 2,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeDocumentationSignDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "width": 570,
                    "options": [
                      {
                        "id": "3231d235-36e3-497a-b244-f1ccd3e4a585",
                        "text": "None",
                        "cascadingParentItemIds": [
                          "402e48f4-a313-4869-9355-91b120a93849",
                          "f68bc4d8-ef25-4f02-acf4-bc20cbe45ab0"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "1b2e9695-0945-4724-85cb-70b4d55bcaf3",
                        "text": "Weak",
                        "cascadingParentItemIds": [
                          "f68bc4d8-ef25-4f02-acf4-bc20cbe45ab0"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "b89239d8-2bad-48ad-b3b9-f1426b0b5b8c",
                        "text": "Noticeable",
                        "cascadingParentItemIds": [
                          "f68bc4d8-ef25-4f02-acf4-bc20cbe45ab0"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "8bc090f5-17c1-4040-9a16-2d4a9b609c94",
                        "text": "Strong",
                        "cascadingParentItemIds": [
                          "f68bc4d8-ef25-4f02-acf4-bc20cbe45ab0"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "4cdee469-9524-4dde-8e24-a878ea8d2138",
                        "text": "Very strong",
                        "cascadingParentItemIds": [
                          "f68bc4d8-ef25-4f02-acf4-bc20cbe45ab0"
                        ]
                      }
                    ],
                    "cascadingParentAttributeId": "ca25c1bc-5528-4730-8cc5-3a3c2ca4428b",
                    "allowsNoValue": true,
                    "cascadingParentInitialValue": [
                      "402e48f4-a313-4869-9355-91b120a93849"
                    ],
                    "value": "3231d235-36e3-497a-b244-f1ccd3e4a585",
                    "attributeType": "ActionAttributeListSingleEntity",
                    "isDirty": false,
                    "clientId": "c75171ee-bd2f-4396-828e-0f909ae538ed_Value",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 1,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeSingleSelectListDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "dependencies": [
                    {
                      "requiresFullUpdate": false,
                      "sourceAttributeId": "ca25c1bc-5528-4730-8cc5-3a3c2ca4428b",
                      "targetAttributeId": "c75171ee-bd2f-4396-828e-0f909ae538ed"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id": "16f18829-e905-498a-8c28-2d29fc2e7b8b",
                  "name": "F3 attribute name",
                  "formulaName": "F3",
                  "definitionId": "9aef853b-f4c3-440d-9c32-6d9a13835033",
                  "isHidden": false,
                  "isReadOnly": false,
                  "isMandatory": true,
                  "label": {
                    "settings": {
                      "bold": false,
                      "underline": false,
                      "color": "#000000",
                      "fontSize": null,
                      "allowTextWrap": true
                    },
                    "text": "F3 attribute name",
                    "colonPosition": 6,
                    "referedClientId": "16f18829-e905-498a-8c28-2d29fc2e7b8b_Value",
                    "clientId": "16f18829-e905-498a-8c28-2d29fc2e7b8b_Label",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 3,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeLabelDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "mandatorySign": {
                    "clientId": "16f18829-e905-498a-8c28-2d29fc2e7b8b_MandatorySign",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 2,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeMandatorySignDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "documentation": {
                    "documentations": [
                      {
                        "id": "096f02b4-2570-47b2-a346-c27c5102ceda",
                        "name": "Attribute documentation",
                        "type": 2
                      }
                    ],
                    "clientId": "16f18829-e905-498a-8c28-2d29fc2e7b8b_Documentation",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 2,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeDocumentationSignDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "width": 570,
                    "rows": 4,
                    "maxLength": 30000,
                    "searchInfo": null,
                    "value": "Textattribute value was changed! ",
                    "attributeType": "ActionAttributeTextEntity",
                    "isDirty": false,
                    "clientId": "16f18829-e905-498a-8c28-2d29fc2e7b8b_Value",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 1,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeTextboxDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "dependencies": []
                }
              ],
              "displayObjects": []
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "e72e24ab-0ebd-4dd8-bf7b-4586dbc50da4",
            "formulaName": "TD1",
            "name": "Remarks",
            "clientId": "627292b8-5854-4413-bd3c-7bc4a683f58d_e72e24ab-0ebd-4dd8-bf7b-4586dbc50da4",
            "nameAdditionalInfos": null,
            "dynamicLayout": {
              "fitToAvailableWidth": false,
              "fillingColumnIndex0Based": null,
              "fitToAvailableHeight": false,
              "fillingRowIndex0Based": null,
              "attributes": [
                {
                  "id": "1ef375a3-fc5b-47dc-8b32-4a106cfa2987",
                  "name": "Remark attribute 1",
                  "formulaName": "R1",
                  "definitionId": "9709e796-3be7-49e5-a638-ed9de027b680",
                  "isHidden": false,
                  "isReadOnly": true,
                  "isMandatory": false,
                  "label": {
                    "settings": {
                      "bold": false,
                      "underline": false,
                      "color": "#000000",
                      "fontSize": null,
                      "allowTextWrap": true
                    },
                    "text": "Remark attribute 1",
                    "colonPosition": 6,
                    "referedClientId": "1ef375a3-fc5b-47dc-8b32-4a106cfa2987_Value",
                    "clientId": "1ef375a3-fc5b-47dc-8b32-4a106cfa2987_Label",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 3,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeLabelDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "mandatorySign": {
                    "clientId": "1ef375a3-fc5b-47dc-8b32-4a106cfa2987_MandatorySign",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 2,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeMandatorySignDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "documentation": {
                    "documentations": [
                      {
                        "id": "d31bb13b-1f12-4f43-8ec4-d91fc405b3ae",
                        "name": "Attribute documentation",
                        "type": 2
                      }
                    ],
                    "clientId": "1ef375a3-fc5b-47dc-8b32-4a106cfa2987_Documentation",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 2,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeDocumentationSignDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "width": 570,
                    "rows": 4,
                    "maxLength": 30000,
                    "searchInfo": null,
                    "value": "",
                    "attributeType": "ActionAttributeTextEntity",
                    "isDirty": false,
                    "clientId": "1ef375a3-fc5b-47dc-8b32-4a106cfa2987_Value",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 1,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeTextboxDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "dependencies": []
                },
                {
                  "id": "379d5451-e5af-42f8-b8b8-52b7f0953261",
                  "name": "Remark attribute 2",
                  "formulaName": "R2",
                  "definitionId": "ba03b62d-bcc1-40c7-9df1-e976151821a2",
                  "isHidden": false,
                  "isReadOnly": true,
                  "isMandatory": false,
                  "label": {
                    "settings": {
                      "bold": false,
                      "underline": false,
                      "color": "#000000",
                      "fontSize": null,
                      "allowTextWrap": true
                    },
                    "text": "Remark attribute 1",
                    "colonPosition": 6,
                    "referedClientId": "379d5451-e5af-42f8-b8b8-52b7f0953261_Value",
                    "clientId": "379d5451-e5af-42f8-b8b8-52b7f0953261_Label",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 3,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeLabelDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "mandatorySign": {
                    "clientId": "379d5451-e5af-42f8-b8b8-52b7f0953261_MandatorySign",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 2,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeMandatorySignDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "documentation": {
                    "documentations": [
                      {
                        "id": "129e84fe-0d76-4f8b-b5aa-e80e452998bd",
                        "name": "Attribute documentation",
                        "type": 2
                      }
                    ],
                    "clientId": "379d5451-e5af-42f8-b8b8-52b7f0953261_Documentation",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 2,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeDocumentationSignDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "width": 570,
                    "rows": 4,
                    "maxLength": 30000,
                    "searchInfo": null,
                    "value": "",
                    "attributeType": "ActionAttributeTextEntity",
                    "isDirty": false,
                    "clientId": "379d5451-e5af-42f8-b8b8-52b7f0953261_Value",
                    "layout": {
                      "positionHorizontal": 1,
                      "positionVertical": 1
                    },
                    "displayWidget": {
                      "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeTextboxDefault",
                      "parameters": null
                    }
                  },
                  "dependencies": []
                }
              ],
              "displayObjects": []
            }
          }
        ],
        "footerLayout": {
          "fitToAvailableWidth": true,
          "fillingColumnIndex0Based": 2,
          "fitToAvailableHeight": false,
          "fillingRowIndex0Based": null,
          "attributes": [
            {
              "id": "AuditComment",
              "name": null,
              "formulaName": "AuditComment",
              "definitionId": "AuditComment",
              "isHidden": false,
              "isReadOnly": false,
              "isMandatory": false,
              "label": {
                "settings": {
                  "bold": false,
                  "underline": false,
                  "color": "#000000",
                  "fontSize": null,
                  "allowTextWrap": false
                },
                "text": "Audit-Trail Comment",
                "colonPosition": 7,
                "referedClientId": "627292b8-5854-4413-bd3c-7bc4a683f58d_EndDateValue",
                "clientId": "627292b8-5854-4413-bd3c-7bc4a683f58d_EndDateLabel",
                "layout": {
                  "positionHorizontal": 3,
                  "positionVertical": 2
                },
                "displayWidget": {
                  "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeLabelDefault",
                  "parameters": null
                }
              },
              "mandatorySign": {
                "clientId": "627292b8-5854-4413-bd3c-7bc4a683f58d_EndDateMandatorySign",
                "layout": {
                  "positionHorizontal": 2,
                  "positionVertical": 2
                },
                "displayWidget": {
                  "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeMandatorySignDefault",
                  "parameters": null
                }
              },
              "documentation": null,
              "value": {
                "width": null,
                "rows": 1,
                "maxLength": null,
                "searchInfo": null,
                "value": "",
                "attributeType": "ActionAttributeTextEntity",
                "isDirty": false,
                "clientId": "627292b8-5854-4413-bd3c-7bc4a683f58d_EndDateValue",
                "layout": {
                  "positionHorizontal": 1,
                  "positionVertical": 2
                },
                "displayWidget": {
                  "identifier": "ActionDetailDisplayTypeTextboxDefault",
                  "parameters": null
                }
              },
              "dependencies": null
            }
          ],
          "displayObjects": null
        }
      },
      "linkedActions": null,
      "documentations": null,
      "approvals": null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please update your example with a valid json document? Otherwise any examples we come up with will not work on your actual doc. For example, is `tabs` contained within `headerLayout`? From the indentation you would guess no, but from the curlies you would guess yes.

Comment: I updated the example with a valid JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do it much easier using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), for example you can get `id` attribute where "formulaName" is "F1" using the following simple JSON Path query:

```
$..[?(@.formulaName == 'F1')].id
```

[image: JSONPath Conditional Select]

Similarly for `definitionId`, just change the above JSON Path query to match it:

```
$..[?(@.formulaName == 'F1')].definitionId
```

---

References:

- [JsonPath Operators](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#operators)
- [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

---

Groovy approach:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

def allAttributes  = json.results.data.actionData.headerLayout.tabs[0].dynamicLayout.attributes

allAttributes.each  {  attribute ->
    attribute.each { k, v -> log.info("${k}:${v}") }
}
```

[image: JSR223 Groovy example]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't described my problem well. I think this approach is not fitting for me because I need to iterate through the formulaNames and generate this definitionIds and ids automatically of on single json response. So I need actually to extract almost all attributes (attributeF1DefinitionId, attributeF2DefinitionId ..., attributeF1Id, attributeF2Id  ...  )

Comment: Well, I still fail to see what are you trying to achieve, however I added an example of iterating through these "attributes" just in case. See [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) and [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) articles for more details.

Comment: How can I use exactly the same JSON path filter query in a groovy script?
`$..[?(@.formulaName == 'F1')].id`
I want to avoid to specify tabs[0]. Because the formulaName could be in any tab. Or how is it done in the groovy snippet you gave me?

Answer (score 1):

With `getJsonResponseString()` returning a string with the json response data as specified in the question ("complete json response"), the below groovy code:

```
import groovy.json.*;

def data = getJsonResponseString()
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data)

def attribute = json.results.data.actionData.tabs.dynamicLayout.attributes.first().find { attribute -> 
  attribute.formulaName == "F1"
}

if (!attribute) {
  println "No attribute with formulaName F1 found!"
} else { 
  println "Results for 'F1': "
  println "  definitionId: ${attribute.definitionId}"
  println "            id: ${attribute.id}"

}
```

prints:

```
Results for 'F1': 
  definitionId: 1dc065a6-f071-4547-835b-603aff165754
            id: ca25c1bc-5528-4730-8cc5-3a3c2ca4428b
```

the `json` object in the above code should be equivalent to the `json` object in your sample code.