# How can I use groovy script in JMeter to check for the existence of a variable in an API response?

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

I'm a newbie to scripting.

I am using Jmeter to test an api and I have to validate the presence of a variable ("witsml") in my response. If this variable is present in the response then my test case should pass, else it should find a difference between two values in my response which is in time format but set as variable ("startDateTime" and "endDateTime") and then fail my test case.

how the groovy script should look for this scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get specific JSON values for a given key of a JMeter response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341347/how-to-get-specific-json-values-for-a-given-key-of-a-jmeter-response)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and the code like:

```
if (prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains(vars.get('witsml'))) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(false)
}
else {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    def delta = (vars.get('endDateTime') as long) - (vars.get('startDateTime') as long)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Unable to find witsml variable value in the response, time difference: '  + delta)
}
```

Where:

- `AssertionResult` stands for [AssertionResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) class instance
- `prev` stands for **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
- `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)